# Find out what are all the columns having NULL values in the table for a given row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

For Example if the table is like below

```
ID  FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  START_DAT END_DATE      SALARY CITY      DESCRIPTION
---- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ---------- -------------------
01   Jason      Martin     25-JUL-96 NULL         1234.56 NULL       Programmer
02   Alison     Mathews    21-MAR-76 21-FEB-86    6661.78 Vancouver  Tester
```

For the  record `ID` "1", `END_DATE` and `CITY` are having null values. How to get these values in a single query?

Comment: Do you mean get the column names, the ids of records with any null value, id and which column(s) is null???

Comment: Yes, the list of column names are having NULL values should be the query result

Comment: See http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/09/25/find-all-columns-having-at-least-a-null-value-from-all-tables-in-the-schema/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` to figure out what has a `NULL` value and concatenate the results together:

```
select ((case when id is null then 'id;' end) ||
        (case when first_name is null then 'firstname;' end) ||
        . . .
        (case when description is null then 'description;' end)
       ) as NullColumns
from table;
```

Note:  Oracle treats NULL values as empty strings for the concatenation operator.

Comment: Thanks Linoff, My table has 260 columns .It is too lengthy to write "case" for all 260 columns. Any other shorter way to get the list of column names with comma separated ?

Comment: Use a decent text editor with a column editing mode, such as Sublime Text, Ultra Edit, etc. Copy the column names from a DESC of the table, then edit to add the statements around the column names.

Comment: @AshokKumar . . . I would normally do that using Excel or a query on `all_tab_cols`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
create or replace function list_null_cols(i_table in varchar2, 
  i_filter in varchar2 default '') return varchar2 is

  v_sql varchar2(32000);
  cursor cols is 
    select column_name cn from user_tab_cols 
      where table_name = upper(i_table) and nullable='Y';
  ret varchar2(32000);
begin
  for c in cols loop
    v_sql := v_sql || 'max(nvl2('||c.cn||',null,'''||c.cn||',''))||';
  end loop;
  if length(v_sql) = 0 then 
    return 'no columns found'; 
  end if;
  v_sql := 'select '||rtrim(v_sql, '|| ') ||' from '||i_table||' '||i_filter;
  begin 
    execute immediate v_sql into ret;
  exception when others then
    return 'error: '||sqlerrm;
  end;
  return rtrim(ret, ',');
end;
```

First parameter is table name, second, optional is `where...` filter. If you omit second parameter all rows in table will be analyzed, like in examples:

```
create table test_table (ID varchar2(2), FIRST_NAME number, LAST_NAME number,  
  START_DATE number, END_DATE number, SALARY number, CITY number, DESCRIPTION number);

insert into test_table values ('01', 1, 1, 1, null, 1, 1, 1);
insert into test_table values ('02', 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, null, 2);

select list_null_cols('test_table') list from dual;

LIST               
-------------------
END_DATE,CITY      

select list_null_cols('test_table', ' where id=''01''') list from dual;

LIST               
-------------------
END_DATE      

select list_null_cols('test_table', ' where salary=2') list from dual;

LIST               
-------------------
CITY
```

Comment: Awesome.Thank you very much. I did copy paste and executed. working as i expected.   You made my job easy.  I learned new things.